# How to test post and put methods in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing tests for the application from one of Spring-REST tutorials (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/), and so far it was pretty clear, but I got stuck by trying to test my post and put methods (with get everything is fine, with delete probably too, not 100% sure though):

```
    @Test
public void getEmployeesStatusIsOk() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/employees"))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
}

@Test
public void deleteEmployeeStatusIsOk() throws Exception {
    var employee = getTestEmployee();
    employee.setId(10L);
    given(this.employeeRepository.existsById(any())).willReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/employees/{id}", 10L))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
}

@Test
public void postEmployeeStatusIsOk() throws Exception {
    given(this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(any()))).willReturn((ResultActions) ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.valueOf("Ok")));
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/employees"))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
}
@Test
public void putEmployeeStatusIsOk() throws Exception
{
    var employee = getTestEmployee();
    employee.setId(1L);
    mockMvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .put("/employees/{id}", 1L)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee))
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
}
```

I'll also leave the methods here in case you need to have a look at them:

```
    @GetMapping("/employees")
public CollectionModel<EntityModel<Employee>> all() {

    List<EntityModel<Employee>> employees = repository.findAll().stream()
            .map(assembler::toModel).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return CollectionModel.of(employees, linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).all()).withSelfRel());
}

@PostMapping("/employees")
ResponseEntity<?> newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee) {

    EntityModel<Employee> entityModel = assembler.toModel(repository.save(newEmployee));

    return ResponseEntity //
            .created(entityModel.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF).toUri()) //
            .body(entityModel);
}


@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
public EntityModel<Employee> one(@PathVariable Long id) {

    Employee employee = repository.findById(id) //
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));

    return assembler.toModel(employee);
}

@PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
ResponseEntity<?> replaceEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee, @PathVariable Long id) {

    Employee updatedEmployee = repository.findById(id) //
            .map(employee -> {
                employee.setName(newEmployee.getName());
                employee.setRole(newEmployee.getRole());
                return repository.save(employee);
            }) //
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                newEmployee.setId(id);
                return repository.save(newEmployee);
            });

    EntityModel<Employee> entityModel = assembler.toModel(updatedEmployee);

    return ResponseEntity //
            .created(entityModel.getRequiredLink(IanaLinkRelations.SELF).toUri()) //
            .body(entityModel);
}

@DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
ResponseEntity<?> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {

    if (!repository.existsById(id)) {
        throw new EmployeeNotFoundException(id);
    }

    repository.deleteById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

Beginnings of the error messages:

Post

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'url' is required

Put

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
> processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Cannot invoke
> "org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel.getRequiredLink(org.springframework.hateoas.LinkRelation)"
> because "entityModel" is null

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is not enough code to see what's wrong. Also please post the whole stacktrace or provide a reproducible example. What strikes me first is that the post has no body

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for some reason, I needed to declare EmployeeModelAssembler through @TestConfiguration, not through @MockBean:

```
    @TestConfiguration
static class ModelAssemblerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public EmployeeModelAssembler getEmployeeAssembler() {
        return new EmployeeModelAssembler ();
    }
}
```

There also was a need to add even two mocks with given for put-test, and of course a content for post body:

```
@Test
public void postEmployeeStatusIsOk() throws Exception {
    var employee = getTestEmployee();
    given(this.employeeRepository.save(any())).willReturn(getTestEmployee());
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/employees")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
}

@Test
public void putEmployeeStatusIsOk() throws Exception
{
    given(this.employeeRepository.findById(any())).willReturn(Optional.of(getTestEmployee()));
    given(this.employeeRepository.save(any())).willReturn(getTestEmployee());
    var employee = getTestEmployee();
    employee.setId(10L);
    mockMvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .put("/employees/{id}", 1L)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee))
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.firstName").value("Max"));
```

And also a mock and value check for get-test, as it was actually doing nothing (returned null, all because of not working EmployeeModelAssembler):

```
@Test
public void getEmployeesStatusIsOk() throws Exception {
    given(this.employeeRepository.findAll()).willReturn(List.of(getTestEmployee()));
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/employees"))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$..employeeList[0].firstName").value("Max"));
}
```